# Delete button or hyperlink to each row of the excel table

Tags: excel

Can i insert a delete button(or hyperlink etc) to every excel table row so that user can delete that current row? Is it even possible with just single line of code like mine below? i can get the current row index to show in a cell but don't know how make that cell have something to click and pass to function with vba :)

I tried to find from microsoft documentation but delete method documentation wasn't helpful so far.

```
Sub Test()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim list As ListObject
Dim row As ListRow

Set sheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set list = sheet.ListObjects(1)
Set row = list.ListRows.Add


row.Range(1, 1).Value = sheet.Range("C7").Value
row.Range(1, 2).Value = sheet.Range("C4").Value
row.Range(1, 3).Value = sheet.Range("C8").Value
row.Range(1, 4).Value = sheet.Range("C6").Value
row.Range(1, 5).Value = sheet.Range("C10").Value
row.Range(1, 6).Value = sheet.Range("C11").Value
row.Range(1, 7).Value = "Delete button" ' call deleteRow and pass id there

End Sub

Sub deleteRow(id)

Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set sheet = ActiveSheet
sheet.ListObjects("Table").ListRows(id).Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this demo code, just paste into a new workbook and run the createTable macro. You should see a table with hyperlinks that delete the row. It may not be suitable for large tables though as it resizes the table and refreshes the links after every deletion.

```vb
     Dim objListObj As ListObject
     Dim objListRows As ListRows

     Sub createTable()
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
         Range("$A1:H10"), , xlNo).Name = "Table1"
         Call addLinks
     End Sub


     Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

       If objListObj Is Nothing Then
         Set objListObj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)
         Set objListRows = objListObj.ListRows
       End If

       ar = Split(Range(Target.SubAddress).Value, " ")
       MsgBox "Deleting Row " & ar(2)
       objListRows(ar(2)).Delete

       Dim newsize As Integer
       Let newsize = objListObj.Range.Rows.Count
       objListObj.Resize Range("A1:H" & newsize)
       Call addLinks

     End Sub

     Sub addLinks()

      Dim ws As Worksheet

      Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
      Set objListObj = ws.ListObjects(1)
      Set objListRows = objListObj.ListRows
      Dim i As Integer, rng As Range

      For i = 1 To objListRows.Count
        Set rng = objListRows(i).Range.Columns(7)
        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, _
        Address:="", SubAddress:=rng.Address, _
        TextToDisplay:="Delete row " & i
      Next i

     End Sub
```